# moved .asp files from windows to linux .html files. can't redirect

Tags: redirect

I have moved my .asp site from windows server to .html files on a linux server using nginx I dont have access to the conf file so i need to redirect the old .asp pages to the new .html.

The .asp files exist on the new server but in htaccess i have this entry
 
AddType application/x-httpd-php .asp
 
Redirect index.asp http://dvmark.com/index.html

it doesn't work I have tried several different ways and no luck. If I delete the .asp pages I get sent to my 404 page which is OK but I would really want the redirect to work so the user doesn't have to find the page they are looking for in the sitemap.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know is to use meta refresh redirect in your asp page like this:

```
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://domaine.org/newpage.html">
    </head>
```